# Nginx reverse proxy on SpringBoot redirect to /forums in nginx directory

Tags: spring, tomcat, nginx

I have a springboot application running on an Nginx server reverse proxy, inside of the nginx WWW root i have a forums directory i want to access via url/forums. So i am trying to setup a proxy for nginx so when someone goes to the website url/forums it will redirect to the nginx forums directory where i will have my PHP forums.

```
    server {
        listen 443 ssl;    # Monitor port
        server_name realmlands.com www.realmlands.com;    # Domain name configuration, can be multiple

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/realmlands.com-0002/fullchain.pem;            # Certificate address
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/realmlands.com-0002/privkey.pem;       # Certificate address

         # Fixed Writing
        ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_protocols   TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers   EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+CHACHA20-draft:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

       # Projects with reverse proxy configuration here
       location /forums {
            proxy_pass https://localhost:8080/forums;

            # Fixed Writing
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        }


        location / {
            proxy_pass https://localhost:8443;

            # Fixed Writing
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        }
    }
```

But what happens when i go to url/forums it seems to redirect the browser to localhost/forums and shows the "This can't be reached".

How can i make it redirect to the nginx forums directory?

Comment: This fragment `proxy_pass http://localhost:443/ /forums/` doesn't make sense.

Comment: it has not been changed to https://localhost:8080/forums but still does not work